# Как найти координаты точки в пространстве по координатам трех других точек и расстоянию до них?

Tags: алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Необходимо найти координаты точки в пространстве, если известны координаты трех других точек и расстояние до них.

Пример
известны три точки

```
А(0,0,0)
B(50,50,50)
C(0,20,20)
```

расстояние до:

```
A = 14.14
B = 75.49
C = 14.14
```

какие координаты

```
D(?,?,?)
```

Comment: Есть три варианта: (1) геометричесий: Строим реугольники, ищем пересечения плоскостей, (2) Аналитический (метод Ньютона для решения системы с 3 неизвестными.) (3) Символьные вычисления. Какой метод вам нужен - зависит от того, что вы изучали ранее ...

Comment: Я бы воспользовался методом градиентного спуска.  Заодно он решит проблему выбора нужной точки из двух возможных, если разместить начальное приближение по нужную сторону от плоскости ABC.

Comment: Это задача называется *трилатерацией*. Алгоритмы аналитического решения есть в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Трилатерация)

Answer (score 0):

У вас получается следующее есть точка с координатами (x1, y1, z1) от неё до точки А(0,0,0) расстояние A = 14.14
Уравнение расстояния dist1 = корень((x1-0)^2 + (y1-0)^2 + (z1-0)^2)
Соответственно для точки В(50,50,50)
Уравнение расстояния dist2 = корень((x1-50)^2 + (y1-50)^2 + (z1-50)^2)
Соответственно для точки C(0,20,20)
Уравнение расстояния dist3 = корень((x1-0)^2 + (y1-20)^2 + (z1-20)^2)
Полчили систему из 3-х уравнений с тремя неизвестными.
А уж как вы будете её решать, хотите, численными методами, хотите вручную сперва выпишите как находятся корни в общем виде. Хотите ищите в википедии.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, три уравнения найти было не сложно, а вот как решить эти три уравнения и как получить координаты у точки D не понятно, чему равно
D_x = ??
D_y = ??
D_z = ?? что бы можно было просто подставить значения и получит ответ

Comment: так в чем проблемы выразить переменные один раз и все? ...